# Why AC main wires or battery poles doesn't attract paper?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

When a glass rod rubbed with silk, it attracts small pieces of paper due to static charge. So why the wires connected to AC main or battery poles does not attract paper?

Nowadays, ceramic capacitors and polymer film capacitors can store charge as a static charge. The devices which used these capacitors also run by AC current source or battery.

if AC main or battery poles can charge ceramic or polymers, then why not paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current-carrying wires do not have a net charge. Every electron that is pushed out of the wire is immediately replaced by an electron from the battery/AC source. Since they carry no static charge, wires cannot attract paper.

Also, on average, an AC source doesn't actually charge a capacitor. Since current alternates directions (hence the name), any charge that is pushed into the capacitor is, one quarter-period later, removed, then replaced with charge of the opposite sign, which is then also removed, over and over again. If you were to connect a capacitor to an AC source and then disconnect it at some random time, you might see some charge on it, depending on when in the AC cycle you disconnected the source. But if you did this many times over, the average of the charge on the capacitor over all trials would be essentially zero.

So let's work in the realm of DC, specifically, as you said, a battery. A battery can indeed charge ceramic/polymer capacitors. But you seem to be under the impression that these capacitors store charge **on** the ceramic/polymer itself, which is untrue. The capacitor consists of two metal plates with some dielectric material in the middle. The charge is stored on the metal plates, and the ceramic/polymer dielectric serves to decrease the electric field between the plates so that more charge can be stored for less applied voltage.

If you were to make a capacitor with a paper dielectric, it wouldn't be nearly as good as a ceramic/polymer one (since paper has a much lower dielectric constant), but it would certainly still work.